# mbstring is missing for phpmyadmin in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, php, phpmyadmin

When I installed phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, it gives me an error mentioned below.

> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

then I tried to install php-mbstring, it says `mbstring is up to date`,
Can anyone help me to solve this?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: If you're using `php-fpm` as well, don't forget to restart that too after installing mbstring > `systemctl restart php-fpm`

Answer (score 58):

Please type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Then, restart apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

---

**Still missing?**

You need to explicitly enable the PHP mcrypt and mbstring extensions, which can do by typing:

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mbstring
```

Then, restart apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Done.
This has been reported here: [PHPMyAdmin requires mbstring](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1577482)

Comment: I did it, but terminal says mbstring is up to date.
anything else to do ?

Comment: I did this,

"sudo phpenmod mcrypt"
sudo phpenmod mbstring
And Restart apache2
sudo systemctl restart apache2,

But mbstring is still missing

Comment: any other solution ?

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to use php 5.6 instead of php 7**

Install php 5.6 mbstring package:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring
```

Then add the following line to the bottom of your php.ini file:

```
extension=php5.6-mbstring.so
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

To find your php.ini file, create a file and insert the following line:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then open with a browser to see where your php.ini file is located.

Comment: aka https://askubuntu.com/a/844619/158442

Comment: Wish I saw that answer sooner haha :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I finally found out that the PHP version that used by phpmyadmin is php5.6 (I have installed php7.0). I found this by executing `phpinfo()` in test.php then I had done this to make phpmyadmin work:

1. By using synaptic package manager, install php5.6,php5.6-mysql,php5.6-mbstring and php5.6-mcrypt
2. Make sure that `extension=mbstring` and `extension=php_mysqli` on `/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini` is not commented
3. Finally, restart your apache `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

I still new at these but hope this works for you.

Comment: This requires a PPA to work - PHP 5.x does not exist in the Xenial repositories.

Comment: This had no upvotes but it worked for me.

Comment: To add to @ThomasWard's comment, a PPA is a personal package archive - in this case one which contains the old PHP 5.6 packages.  The command that you want is `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`  before `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring` will work on Ubuntu 18.4