# Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist ,mbstring is missing, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, phpmyadmin, php7

[image]

```
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

I have also enabled these as instructed in other sites by

`shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Tried the solution given here.[mbstring is missing for phpmyadmin in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772397/mbstring-is-missing-for-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-16-04)

```
shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

is giving this result.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.0-common' instead of 'php-gettext'
E: Unable to locate package php-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mbstring
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-mbstring'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mbstring'
```

then I tried those steps

```
shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

and then

```
shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo phpenmod mbstring
```

which gave this output.

```
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
WARNING: Module mbstring ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
```