# Installing and configuring LAMP + phpmyadmin in Ubuntu xenial LTS 16.04

Tags: server, php, phpmyadmin

I managed to find a PPA with php5.6 but when installed phpmyadmin from normal ubuntu packages, everything seemed to be fine until i visited 0.0.0.0/phpmyadmin.
It said:

`The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.`

Even tho I have uncommented it and restarted apache2, I still got this error which got me thinking which php.ini was phpmyadmin loading it from?
Probably from a PHP 7.1 install that I don't even have so I want to ask how do I install phpmyadmin for PHP 5.6 in ubuntu 16.04 where PHP 5.6 doesn't apear in official packages anymore.

**NOTE** This is a fresh install of ubuntu-server 16.04.1 LTS using PPA of PHP 5.6

list of php installed packages:

```
root@*****:~# apt list --installed | grep php
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
libapache2-mod-php5.6/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed]
php-common/xenial,xenial,now 1:49+deb.sury.org~xenial+4 all [installed,automatic]
php-phpseclib/xenial,xenial,now 2.0.1-1build1 all [installed,automatic]
php5.6/xenial,xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 all [installed]
php5.6-cli/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed]
php5.6-common/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php5.6-json/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php5.6-mbstring/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed]
php5.6-mcrypt/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed]
php5.6-mysql/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed]
php5.6-opcache/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php5.6-readline/xenial,now 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
phpmyadmin/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2 all [installed]
```

Comment: What version of php are you using, and did you _enable_ `mbstring` in `apache`?

Comment: For mbstring extension, try this: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring`.

Comment: `php5.6-mbstring is already the newest version (5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1)`
I think it's phpmyadmin that is trying to use php7 when it should use php5.6 (and find mbstring is installed) and I want to know if it's possible to change this

Comment: this is a fresh install of ubuntu-server 16.04 LTS
I didn't change anything, the only change I did was uncommenting the mbstring line in php.ini file, everything else is default

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mbstring is missing for phpmyadmin in ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/772397/mbstring-is-missing-for-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: it is not duplicate.. that solution is for php 7
now php 5.6 is not officially supported in ubuntu 16.04 so solutions from that will not work on this workaround, it's a special case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** In `/etc/php/x.x/apache2/php.ini` has a line `;extension=php_mbstring.dll`. In this case, this is just an example. Files with `.dll` extensions are libraries for Windows. Equivalent extensions for Ubuntu are `.so` - check your `/etc/php/5.6/mods-available/mbstring.ini` for example.

The easiest way to enable PHP modules in Ubuntu is through the command `phpenmod`. So you need:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring
sudo phpenmod mbstring
```

**2.** To enable PHP 5.6 for Apache2 you need to:

- Install the library:

  ```
  sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php5.6
  ```
- Disable `php7.x` modules:

  ```
  sudo a2dismod php7.0 && sudo a2dismod php7.1
  ```
- Enable `php5.6` module:

  ```
  sudo a2enmod php5.6
  ```

**3.** Restart Apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

**4.** Check your PHP configuration:

- Create `phpinfo.php` file in `/var/www/html/` (if this is your DocumentRoot Directory):

  ```
  echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | sudo tee /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
  ```
- Open `phpinfo.php` in your web browser, and check your current PHP configuration: `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`.

Comment: it worked but I had to install php-gettext and configure .htaccess file