# PHP7.0 mbstring not working after dist-upgrade 17.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I just upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 and ever since my phpmyadmin is not working anymore. It displays:
`The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.`

I have tried all the options here: [mbstring is missing for phpmyadmin in ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772397/mbstring-is-missing-for-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-16-04) but to no avail.
`sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring` doesn't work because it has no install candidate, but I did install php-mbstring. I also enabled the mods, but when I then hit `php -i` in my console I get:
`Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mbstring.so'`

I did of course (plenty of) apache restarts.
How do I get this to work again?

Comment: seems 17.10 uses php 7.1, or at least that lets this links information conclude --> https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/php/php-mbstring. maybe try downloading the package `php-mbstring` but that as well would mean you might have to update all your php to 7.1. SInce I'am still on 17.04 I can not entirely confirm this therefore I only put a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appeared to be that 17.10 uses php7.1 and not php7.0 as indicated by [Videonauth](https://askubuntu.com/users/522934/videonauth). I resolved it as follows:

```
sudo apt remove php7.0
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install php7.1
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For some reason it does install php7.1, but somehow not everything php7.1 requires (such as php7.1-cli), so I installed it manually to get the missing dependencies. In my case some other php7.0 packages remained such as `php7.0-common` and `php7.0-cli` which I removed after the `autoremove`.

For me, phpmyadmin itself was removed as well when I removed `php7.0`, so I did another

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

to get everything to work.